# Haskell: function composition with anonymous/lambda function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

While studying for a Functional Programming exam, I came across the following question from a previous test:

```
t1 = (reverse . take 2 . words . \ _ -> name)"!"
```

The task is to write the output of the statement. The variable name refers to the student's name, written in the form "Smith, John". If I enter the statement into WinHugs, I get the following output:

```
["John","Smith,"]
```

I understand what the functions reverse, take and words are doing and I understand how the . operator connects them. What I don't understand is what is happening here:

```
\ _ -> name
```

What are the slash, underscore and "arrow" for? Also, what does the exclamation point in quotation marks do? (nothing?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a lambda function that discards its (only) argument (i.e. "!") and yields `name`.

As another lambda example, the following would be a lambda function that squares its argument:

```
\x -> x * x
```

The `\` is the notation used to introduce a lambda function.

The `_` means "variable about whose name we do not care".

The `->` separates the lambda function's arguments from the expression used to specify its result.

Comment: Good explanation. I am still somewhat confused by the exclamation mark though. Do you want to say that in this case the exclamation mark is added only for obfuscation?

Comment: The `"!"` is the value that is being ignored. The exclamation mark is just a character in a string that's being ignored: ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing there is an anonymous function, or lambda function (that name comes from lambda calculus). The backslash tells you that you are starting the function. The underscore says that the function takes one argument and ignores it. The arrow points from the argument list to the result - in this case, it ends up ignoring its argument and returning the name. Essentially, `\_ -> name` is the same as `const name`.

Answer (score 3):

A constant anonymous function: which ever the argument, return `name`.

Haskell's lambda expressions (i.e. anonymous functions) come in this form:

```
\x -> f x
```

where `x` is an argument, and `f x` an expression using this argument. The special variable `_` matches anything and treats it as unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

The "slash" is part of a lambda [function](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html), the underscore is a "wildcard" used in patterns (it is discarded). The arrow is another part of the lambda function. The function `\ _ -> name` returns the name, regardless of input, so the "!" does nothing but provide (unused) input to the function.